# Passing an argument using paste

Tags: r

This should be a duplicate, but I cannot find the right question and answer.

In R, in a loop I would like to pass as argument a variable of a dataframe using paste, since there is a changing part of the name.

What I would like to do is:

```
for (i=1 to 5) {
  myResult <- myFunction(hello=firstArg, world=paste0("someData$myVar", i))
}
```

But it does not work, although if as a test I use `world=someData$myVar1` it works.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  A good rule of thumb when programming in R is "If I'm thinking of using a loop, there's probably a better way of doing it".  This may be a case in point, but it's difficult to be sure because your problem is not [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Here, if you're using the tidyverse, `across` is an obvious option.  In base R, `someData[[myPastedVarName]] <- someNewValue` may be an option.  Other solutions exist.

Comment: We can't help without seeing the function definition. Code like `paste0("someData$myVar",i)` looks like you are trying to compute on the language, which should not be done with character strings. Also, quite frequently, people who write such code don't know that they should just use `[...]` instead of `$`. So maybe study `help("$")`.

Comment: Thank you for these two comments, I will follow those leads. Indeed the problem is that the result of paste0 is a string and not a dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments I have finally found a solution, I'm posting it so the question gets closed, and it might help others.

Say the data frame someData first has 27 variables and then myVar1 in position 28, myVar2 in position 29 and so on. The following works in my case.

```
offset <- 27 

for (i=1 to 5) {
  myLocalVar <- as.data.frame(someData[, offset + i])
  myResult <- myFunction(hello=firstArg, world=myLocalVar[, 1])
}
```

Comment: `for(i=1 to 5){..}` does not look like valid R syntax.

Comment: You're right, it is for(i in 1:5)

Comment: That seems quite convoluted and needlessly inefficient: first you create a temporary data.frame from a single column vector, and then you extract that column again to pass it to the function. Why not pass the single column directly, without the pointless detour via the temporary data.frame? `myFunction(hello = firstArg, world = someData[, offset + i])`?

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph : technically you're right but in my code there are explicit names and it is more readable this way for me.

Comment: @Archie Having a temporary variable isn’t the issue. The issue is that you needlessly create a data.frame. Just keep the vector without wrapping it into `data.frame()` and subsequently extracting it again.